# Wrong path to static files in production mode in Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, production

I've created an application using Vue.js and run `npm run build`. After the finishing a process `dist` folder appeared, BUT paths to static files are wrong. Everywhere it adds `'/'` before every path. Smth like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.5563dab9fc515679fa52.js"></script>`.
But it is wrong. It has to be without a forward slash before `static` folder.

**In development mode the file structure in `src` looks like:**

[image]

**In production mode like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**
I just changed `index.js` file in `config` folder.

**From:** `assetsPublicPath: '/'`

**To:** `assetsPublicPath: ''`